Apisix route OIDC plugin to connect to Zitadel odic not accessible within the same cluster
Configured Apisix and Zitadel in kind cluster with single node configuration (contr).

kind cluster config

kind: Cluster
apiVersion: kind.x-k8s.io/v1alpha4
name: api6-zitadel
nodes:
- role: control-plane
  kubeadmConfigPatches:
  - |
    kind: InitConfiguration
    nodeRegistration:
      kubeletExtraArgs:
        node-labels: "ingress-ready=true"
  extraPortMappings:
  - containerPort: 30080
    hostPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
  - containerPort: 30443
    hostPort: 443
    protocol: TCP



kind cluster info

$ k get nodes
NAME                         STATUS   ROLES           AGE   VERSION
api6-zitadel-control-plane   Ready    control-plane   37m   v1.29.2

Note:- the hosts file was updated with 127..0.0.1 localhost apisix.localhost zitadel.localhost backend.localhost

Installed Apisix ingress controller and Apisix route for Apisix dashboard and zitadel ui

apisix dashboard route


# use v1beta1 if your Kubernetes cluster version is older than v1.19.0
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: api6-dashboard-ingress
  namespace: ingress-apisix
spec:
  ingressClassName: apisix
  rules:
  - host: apisix.localhost
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: apisix-dashboard
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix



Zitadel UI configuration

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: api6-zitadel-ingress
spec:
  ingressClassName: apisix
  rules:
  - host: zitadel.localhost
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: zitadel
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix

Note:-
When configuring the zitadel, the ExternalDomain was set as zitadel.localhost.

With the above configuration, from the browser I am able to access both Zitadel and Apisix UI's.

Created a simple nginx backend to an endpoint /greet. The configuration looks like below.


apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: backend-app
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: backend-nginx-config
  namespace: backend-app
data:
  nginx.conf: |
    worker_processes auto;
    error_log stderr notice;
    events {
      worker_connections 1024;
    }
    http {
      variables_hash_max_size 1024;

      log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [%time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
      access_log off;
      real_ip_header X-Real-IP;
      charset utf-8;

      server {
        listen 80;
        
        location /greet {
          default_type application/json;
          return 200 '{"status":"OK","message":"Greetings!! from server"}';
        }
        location /hello {
          default_type text/html;
          return 200 '<html><body><div>status: <b>OK</b></div><div>message:<b>Hello!! from server</b></div></body></html>';
        }
      }
    }

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: backend-server
  namespace: backend-app
  labels:
    app: backend-server
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: backend-server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: backend-server
    spec:
      volumes:
       - name: nginx-config
         configMap:
           name: backend-nginx-config
           items:
           - key: nginx.conf
             path: nginx.conf
      containers:
      - name: backend-server
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
         - name: nginx-config
           mountPath: /etc/nginx
        resources:
          requests: 
            memory: "128Mi"
            cpu: "250m"
          limits:
            memory: "256Mi"
            cpu: "500m"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: backend-svc
  namespace: backend-app
spec:
  selector:
    app: backend-server
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8081
      targetPort: 80

---


In Apisix, created a route with below configuration and look like below
The discovery url is not accessible since the apisix pod adds this configuration and reports not able to connect.
The Apisix discovery is configured with kubernetes registry.

{
  "uri": "/greet",
  "name": "backend-greet",
  "methods": ["GET"],
  "host": "backend.localhost",
  "plugins": {
    "openid-connect": {
      "_meta": {
        "disable": false
      },
      "bearer_only": false,
      "client_id": "***********",
      "client_secret": "****--******--*****",
      "discovery": "http://zitadel.localhost",
      "introspection_endpoint": "http://zitadel.localhost/oauth/v2/introspect",
      "realm": "master"
    }
  },
  "upstream": {
    "nodes": [
      {
        "host": "backend-svc.backend-app",
        "port": 8081,
        "weight": 10
      }
    ],
    "timeout": {
      "connect": 6,
      "send": 6,
      "read": 6
    },
    "type": "roundrobin",
    "scheme": "http",
    "pass_host": "pass",
    "keepalive_pool": {
      "idle_timeout": 60,
      "requests": 1000,
      "size": 320
    }
  }
}

Since Zitadel is configured with ExternalDomain as zitadel.localhost, when APISIX route configuration plugin discovery url is set to http://zitadel.localhost it was not accessible.
I tried to configure the service name http://zitadel.zitadel:80/, Zitadel redirects and says domain name didn't match.
As a work around, created a namespace as localhost and helm release name as zitadel, which made the service to be zitadel.localhost and that was able to provide a redirect_url.
Question :-

How to setup the Zitadel ODIC plugin in APISIX to access the http://zitadel.localhost without making any work-around. Created an externalName type service to the zitadel.localhost to access from the laptop, but didn't work.

